# PIV Analysis, Interrogation Area of The Cross Correlation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signals, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I'm running a PIV analysis on two consecutive images taken during an experiment to get the vector field. But I would like to know, based on what criteria do I have to choose the percentage of overlap between the tow images for the cross-correlation process? 50%, 75%...? The PIVlab_GUI tool designed for MATLAB chooses a 50% overlap by default, but it allows changing it.
I just want to know the criteria based on which I can know how much overlap is best? Do the vectors become less accurate, dependent.etc, as we increase/decrease the overlap?
My book "Fluid Mechanics Measurements" does not explain how to choose the overlap amount in the cross-correlation process, and I could not find any helpful online reference.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on spectral estimation - which is basically equivalent to cross correlation when you segment the data and average the correlation estimates calculated from each segment (the cross correlation is the inverse Fourier transform of the cross spectrum). There's a book chapter on this stuff [here](http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/astrophysik/HEA/internal/Numerical_Recipes/f13-4.pdf), but you may want to find a more complete resource if you are unclear on the basics.

A short answer: increasing the overlap will increase the frequency resolution of the spectral estimate, and give you more segments to average over; your estimate will have a lower variance. But there are diminishing statistical returns the more you increase your overlap past 50%, while the computational complexity continues to rise (more segments = more calculations). Hence most people just choose 50% and have done with it.

It's important to note that you don't get any more **information** by using overlapping frames, you are simply increasing the frequency resolution (or time lag resolution, for correlation) - similar to the effect of zero-padding a signal before taking its Fourier transform - and this has statistical effects due to the way estimation of this type works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wakjah. I'm learning a lot from your answer
But as you may have noticed from my question, I'm just a beginner in the field of PIV and using cross-correlation in general.
So basically, if I use a 75% interrogation area instead of 50%, will I get many 'invalid' vectors? or will they be inaccurate? I heard from one colleague that a larger interrogation area leads to low resolution, but I'm not sure what's supposed to mean (I'd appreciate it if you can explain it away from the frequency domain, apparently for background reasons). I wanna know to decide the best interrogation area size

Comment: The answer is the same in the time domain as in the frequency domain. Longer windows will give you more frequency (time lag) resolution, with less bias; but the variance will be larger, cos you average over fewer frames. Shorter windows do the opposite. More overlap is not a bad thing; you will get less variance in your estimate of the cross correlation because you average over more frames; but there is always a trade-off between bias and variance in an estimator. If you just use 50%, you will be fine. I can't explain the whole theory here; if you really want to understand, you need a book.